# monaco-editor: limit api calls on registerInlineCompletionsProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am trying to implement inline completions similar to what copilot does on vscode. I built the backend API that will get a request with the current code in the editor and respond with the completion.

But when I added the completionProvider implementation I noticed every single new character triggers a new completion event.

I want to be able to limit the number of calls to the backend API, so that the API will be invoked only when the cursor doesn't move for 2 seconds (the user stops typing).

I tried setTimeout/clearTimeout like this:

```
const [autocTimeoutID, setAutocTimeoutID] = useState(null)
...

provideInlineCompletions: async (model, position, context, token) => {
    if (autocTimeoutID) {
        clearTimeout(autocTimeoutID)
    }
    setAutocTimeoutID(setTimeout(async()=>{
        console.log('will call inline completion')

        //api call goes here...

    }, 2000))
}
```

But that doesn't prevent the API call to be called multiple times because autocTimeoutID never gets updated, so it does not cancel the running timeout before starting a new one.  My guess is that parent component is not aware of the events happening inside the editor and does not know it has to update state and re-render.

So my question is how to implement the completion provider so it ignores the events  when they happen in a 2 second interval from each other (it could simply return '' as a suggestion).

Thanks,

Comment: I can't look it up currently, but believe there's a VS Code setting for the code completion delay.

Comment: There is a delay for quick suggestions, not for inline completion.  But it looks like you can have quick suggestions type as 'inline', although that would not be ideal for me.  Maybe I will try to submit a PR with a change in the future.